# Display multiple arrays in HandlebarsJS

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, handlebars.js

I am having my first play with HandlebarsJS and I am looking to use multiple arrays within it. Is this possible?

I have setup a Codepen template but I am struggling to implement the data from 2 arrays and from an external URL. I have tried this with MustacheJS too, but I believe that only allows one array and no filtering- unlike Handlebars

Here is the [external JSON](http://myjson.com/kjs8l)
and the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rJaGNY?page=2)

```
<!-- REQUIRED - Display site name, url and title in top section. With product data below using the "other array-->
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{content}}
</script>

<div id="contentArea"></div>

<script>
var data     = {"content": "Hello, World!"};
var source   = $("#myTemplate").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var html     = template(data);
$("#contentArea").text(html);
</script>
```

Here is [my first template attempt](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BYywdz?page=2) but failing to integrate the JSON array at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible using `{{#each}}` block helper. I also registered my own helper `{{{s}}}`, which simply returns it's argument `JSON.stringify()`'ied, so I can print those arrays. How you fetch them is another problem, I <kbd>Copy</kbd> & <kbd>Paste</kbd> them into the Javascript part of the code for simplicity. Also, here's [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wscourge/vjnzjqup/):

```js
var data = {"content": "Hello, World!", "multipleArrays": [
  [
    {
      "productimage": "https://c.static-nike.com/a/images/t_PDP_864_v1/f_auto/i0lfddlghaiwfqlvlqay/air-vortex-shoe-fmq6pS.jpg",
      "producturl": "https://www.nike.com/gb/t/air-vortex-shoe-fmq6pS"
    },
    {
      "productimage": "https://c.static-nike.com/a/images/t_PDP_864_v1/f_auto/cmuof8adhfipkvd0f43r/air-max-95-shoe-XPTbV2mM.jpg",
      "producturl": "https://www.nike.com/gb/t/air-max-95-shoe-XPTbV2mM"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "sitename": "Nike",
      "sitetitle": "Nike. Just Do It.. Nike.com",
      "siteurl": "https://www.nike.com/gb/en_gb/"
    }
  ]
]};

Handlebars.registerHelper('s', function(arg) {
  return JSON.stringify(arg);
})
var source = $("#myTemplate").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var html = template(data);
$("#contentArea").html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.11/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<!-- REQUIRED - Display site name, url and title in top section. With product data below using the "other array-->
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <h1>Content: {{content}}</h1>
  <hr>
    
  <h2>Stringified multiple arrays:</h2> 
  {{{s multipleArrays}}}
  <hr>
    
  {{#each multipleArrays}}
   <h2>Item {{@index}}</h2>
  {{{s this}}}
  <br>
  <br>
  {{/each}}
  
  
</script>

<div id="contentArea">
</div>
```

Comment: This is looking good, can it be done by linking to that JSON url source (myjson). As the feed I have cannot edit the output of the JSON. So that it what we are working with. I assumeI can then output the elements into <p> tags and <a>, <img> tags under the each to properly output.

Comment: Culd it worth switching to Angular or something else to be able do this with multiple arrays?

Comment: Found this where Underscore allows the merge of arrays, not sure whether it would work with Handlebars https://lostechies.com/chrismissal/2012/10/05/extending-objects-in-underscore/